# Javascript function , which takes a month/date and disply 12 months/dates back

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any `javascript` function which takes one input parameter `(e.g 04/2014 )` and return
`12` months and dates with the same format

(`e.g 04/2013`.........................................`04/2014`)

i have this one

```
  function calcFullMonth(startDate) {
    //copy the date
    var dt = new Date(startDate);
    dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth() - 1);

    return dt;
}
```

The logic that i have is this .But it gives me only one month back
I need to get 12 months and 1 year back and display them as you see second e.g.

Thanks

Comment: so you want 12 months back date? right?

Comment: Yes , and months also with the same format of startdate  (e.g 06/2014)

Comment: From [here](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2009/01/07/javascript-add-a-month-to-a-date/) you could do [this.](http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/2w6Yz/)

Comment: As Far i understood it You want to Fetch last twelve Months ,eg if you supplied march you want march,feb,jan.....April?

Comment: yes. Because i am gonna display in a chart axis as variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call your original function as many times as you need, and store them in an array.

```
function calcFullMonth(startDate, num) {
    var months = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        var dt = new Date(startDate);
        dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth() + i);
        months[i] = dt;
    }
    return months;
}
```

For example, to get the current month until this month next year, use `num = 13`

```
console.log(calcFullMonth(new Date(), 13));
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wH77V/)

Comment: what date format i should try ? i did , var startDate="06/2014" and var num=13;  didnt work in fiddle

Comment: @jasonstone, it returns a list of [date objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Examples). You need to pass them to a formatter to get them in the format you need.

Comment: Ok. But why i couldn't run your c0de in fiddle . It is not giving me any result

Comment: @jasonstone, the result is printed to your developer console, in chrome, press `F12` and go to `console` tab

Comment: ok i also updated dt.getMonth() + i);  to dt.getMonth() - i); and it works as i want , thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following function

```
function Get12MonthBack(input) {
    var year = input.split("/")[1];
    var month = input.split("/")[0];

    var d = new Date(year, month);

    d.setMonth(d.getMonth()-12);

    return (d.getMonth().toString().length == 1 ? "0" + d.getMonth() : d.getMonth()) + "/" + d.getFullYear();
}
```

**Tests**

```
Get12MonthBack("03/2011")
"03/2010"
Get12MonthBack("11/2012")
"11/2012"
```